# Confusing way to invoke JavaScript arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I came across the following code which is very simple as it's meant to determine whether a variable is a string or not.

```
const is_string = value => {
  return typeof value() === 'string';
};

let example = 'Hello, world!';

console.log(is_string(() => example)); // true
```

My confusion is related to the use of the input parameter. Specifically the second line with the parenthesis after the parameter: `value()` and the way the function is invoked: `is_string(() => example)`. The later looks like an arrow function in itself.

I rewrote the code like

```
const is_string = (value) => {
  return typeof value === 'string';
};

let example = 'Hello, world!';

console.log(is_string(example)); // true
```

and it does pretty much the same, so what is the real difference/advantage of using the notation of the first code? Is it useful in specific cases?

Thanks in advance.

EDITION:

The key word in this discussion is the **Lambda expression**. I was not fully aware the code was passing a function as the input parameter, I wasn't familiar with that notation.

Comment: It's certainly useful in some cases, but in this one? eh, questionable. Note that your snippet can't throw an error, so the try catch isn't necessary.

Comment: The first one literally tests if the return type of the function passed in as an argument is a string, not if the argument passed in is a string, which is what the second one is testing.  These are quite different.

Comment: The first function seems to be a partial implementation of a pattern where a function may accept either a value or a lambda returning a value, for flexibility. e.g. it could have done: `return typeof (typeof value === 'function' ? value() : value)` In its current form, it doesn't look useful.

Comment: @KevinB I had deleted other stuff for the sake of simplicity. I edited the code, apologies for that.

Comment: Accepting a function as a parameter in general is a relatively common practice, but accepting one who's sole purpose is to return a value that you check the type of? that's... odd. i can't see that being useful outside of testing frameworks... and even then...

Comment: `const is_string = value => { switch (typeof value) { case "function": return typeof value() === "string"; case "string": return true; default: return; } }`

Comment: Thank you @AteşGöral for all your comments, you helped me out to understand this was all about lambda expressions. Now I will go and look more into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you’re passing a function and evaluating whether the return value of that function is a string.

In the latter case you’re testing the argument itself.

As presented in your examples, where it’s just an arrow function that returns a variable you already have, there’s no point in turning it into an arrow function and doing so incurs a (tiny) bit of memory and performance overhead. Passing the value directly is unquestionably the better approach.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be asking what the functions do. The question is more about the "why".

Comment: But if you understand what they do, doesn’t the “why” become self-explanatory?

Comment: @AteşGöral The "Why" is that these two functions are valid tests for different things,  but the OP is confused and thinks they do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you @Tibrogargan for all your comments, you helped me out to understand the real meaning of that code. My confusion was the lambda expression, now I understand it returns a single result and that can be passed to other functions. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @andres_v I think maybe you've fallen victim to the common practice of using contrived examples in order to explain a feature of the language.  As ray hatfield mentions (as well as Kevin B), the method is odd at best